# iTKO/CA LISA and file feeds

Tags: files

I test an application that accepts several csv files from an external system. My application loads those files in a database applies business logic to the received raw data and futher processes it. The external system test environment is often down and that hurts my testing window.

Can LISA help me in virtualizing this scenario where I can mock files (I know the file formats, data definitions). Also, does it offer a switch to jump between real and mocked feeds?

Comment: Is there a specific need to know about LISA? Or are you open to alternatives if they exist?

Comment: Yes, LISA only.

Comment: How are the csv files sent to your system? Are they pulled from a ftp-server or are they sent in SOAP messages?